# Drupal 6 Chart module doesn't show up legends and its associated colors

Tags: php, charts, drupal-6, pie-chart

I'm using Drupal 6 chart module with google plugin. My graph type is pie3d. I'm unable to set legends and color associations to these legends.

```
    $chart = array(
          '#plugin'    => 'google',
          '#type'     => 'pie3D', // Display a 3D pie chart
          '#color'    => 'f0f0f0', // Background color, in RRGGBB format
          '#width'    =>  '470',
          '#title'    => t('Data Analysis'), // Chart title
          array(
                    array('#value' => $notstarted, '#label' => t('Not Started'),'#legend' => t('#A35f23'),),
                    array('#value' => $partial, '#label' => t('Partial'),'#legend' => t('#A35f23')),
                    array('#value' => $completed, '#label' => t('Completed'),'#legend' => t('#A35f23'))
                ),
        );
echo charts_chart($chart);
```

Above is my code.